# How to add file extensions to list of acceptable in IMCE

Tags: files

I am using Ckeditor editor/IMCE file upload. 
How do I get to the config settings where I can add more extensions which are accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding additional **buttons and plug-ins** to add more extra functionalities,just follow these steps:-

1. Go to the **CONFIGURATION** (`admin/config`) option which is displayed on the menu bar.
2. Then select **WYSIWYG PROFILES** which is part of Content Authoring section.
3. For the **three text formats** available (i.e FULL HTML, FILTERED HTML, PLAIN TEXT), configure the **CK EDITOR** for the format you wish to configure for.
4. Then select **EDIT** which is displayed in the operations's section.
5. Go to **BUTTONS AND PLUG-INS** link.
6. **Check the checkboxes** for the functionality you want to enable in your ck editor.
7. **Save** the settings.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **admin/config/content/wysiwyg**. Under the textformat table if CKEditor is choosen on full html for example under the operations column, select edit. And you should see buttons and plugins, and you should find the Imce checkbox listed as one of the last checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

I found this question in trying to add to the list of permitted file extensions for uploaded files using IMCE. Following the accepted answer didn't get me where I needed to go. Instead I had to go to Admin > Configuration > Media > IMCE, then click to edit the profile I needed to adjust (Admin, in my case).

From there (`example.com/admin/config/media/imce/profile/edit/3`), I was able to add to the list under "Permitted file extensions". I hope this helps for other folks who land on this thread.

FYI, I'm using Wysiwyg version 7.x-2.2+63-dev, IMCE Wysiwyg API bridge version 7.x-1.0, and IMCE version 7.x-1.9.